# Q: How to properly work with cookies and sessions for IdentityServer4

Tags: session, cookies, identityserver4

Can someone explain how to properly setup sessions and cookies with Identity Server 4?

Using: 
Login site
- IdentityServer4
- MVC EntityFramework Identity

Main site
- MVC, Client grant type: HybridAndClientCredentials
- In Startup: UseCookieAuthentication / UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication

What I currently have working:
- Login on IdentityServer - Cookie lifetime 5 days
- Go to site logs in, cookie lifetime session?
- wait a while, refresh page redirects to login site and goes back to site works

Not working
- wait a while refresh (javascript/ajax) grid, failes. Because ajax call gets redirected to login, but doesn't reinit session.

So how to either get site cookie/session to also stay for several days / sliding lifetime. Or how do I get the script/ajax call to properly refresh the session.

Thanks for any help in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Check your access token lifetime if you have set it or not. Although your cookie time is 5 days, but access token lifetime is less than this ( on top of my head i think its 3600s/1hr) So when "**after a while**" (not sure how much time it is) you refresh, make sure your access token is still valid, if not you have to redirect the client app to the auth server as they have to log in again ( you can do this by logging them out ) . If you don't want to ask user to login every time when access token expires, you can use refresh tokens to renew access token.